# What is the musical form of Kamasi Washington's "Truth"?

Tags: theory, jazz, musical-forms

I'm pretty new to music theory, so I have been analyzing songs I enjoy for practice. I thought I was getting decent at it, but the length and complexity of this song has been giving me some trouble.

[Kamasi Washington - "Truth"](https://vimeo.com/216562943)

Comment: Welcome to Music practice & theory StackExchange. Do you have a link to a recording and/or a score?

Comment: @Karlo Fixed. Added the link into the post

Answer (score 0):

This piece can be analyzed on a two different levels: the small-scale repeating form and the large-scale structure of the whole 13 and a half minute recording.

The small-scale structure is really simple. It is a two-chord vamp consisting of four measures of Gmaj7 followed by four measures of F#-7. That's it. It's just those two chords over and over.

The large-scale structure is only slightly more complicated. The piece is kind of an overture for his Harmony of Difference EP. Kamasi is taking melodic elements from the other five compositions on the album and layering on top of one another.

Analyzing these melodic elements is the fun part, so I won't spoil it for you, but if you want to get serious about it, I recommend looking at those first five tunes on the album so that you can identify the various elements that he's working with.